# Calculate $\int_Ue^{(x-y)/(x+y)}dxdy$, where $U=\{(x,y)\mid x\geq0,y\geq0,x+y\leq1\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Calculate $\int_Ue^{(x-y)/(x+y)}dxdy$, where $U=\{x\geq0,y\geq0,x+y\leq1\}$

I tried making the following change of variables:

$u=x$, with $0\leq u\leq 1$, and $v=x+y$, with $0\leq v\leq1$

Jacobian is $1$, then I have $\int_0^1\int_0^1e^{\frac{2u-v}{v}}dudv$

Then I tried $u=x-y$, so the function would be $e^{\frac{u}{v}}$

It is a bit simpler, but almost the same thing. Is there a easier way to calculate it? I coudn't get it not even with integral calculators.

Comment: Hint: for the integral of $e^{u/v}$, evaluate the integral over $u$ first, treating $v$ as a constant; then you can look at a substitution like $w=\frac1v$ to handle the resulting integral.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it was a mess.

Comment: The change of variable $(u,v)=(x-y,x+y)$ seems most natural and yields $$\frac12\int_De^{u/v}dudv$$ with $D=\{(u,v)\mid|u|<v<1\}$. Can you evaluate this?

Comment: I tried that, the first integral is ok, but I'll have then to integrate $ve^{2/v}$, I tried doing $w=1/v$, but it just got worse.

Comment: Sorry but no: for $v>0$, what is the result of $$\int_{-v}^v\frac12e^{u/v}du\ ?$$

Comment: Hint: $2\sinh(1) v$.

Comment: @Did I thought I got the limits of integration wrong then. I put from $0$ to $2$. Why from $-v$ to $v$?

Comment: @BrunoMazeto Because you have to transform the limits of your integration along with your variables.

Comment: $x+y = v\leq 1$, $x-y=u$, so $2y=v-u\geq0\Rightarrow u\leq v$ and $2x = u+v \geq 0 \Rightarrow u\geq -v$ Got it! Thanks

Comment: "Why from $−v$ to $v$?" Sorry but did you even read the domain $D$ in my first comment?

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I understood an put it in a comment above. Thanks it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u=x+y, v = x-y$ rotates your coordinate axes.[image]

Hopefully the picture makes it clear why your limits of integration are

$\frac 12 \int_0^1\int_{-u}^u e^{\frac vu}\ dv\ du\\
\frac 12 \int_0^1u e^{\frac vu}|_{-u}^u\ du\\
\frac 12 \int_0^1 u (e - e^{-1})\ du\\
\frac 14 (e - e^{-1})$